# Explicitly allocate physical/virtual memory in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, parallel-processing, virtual-memory

i would like to know if it is possible to explicitly declare which memory type (physical or virtual memory) should be used by the C# application for performing different actions? Let me explain it by an example:

Lets say, i have a file of about 100 or 200 MB in size. I need to parse this file, access and analyze its contents and perform operations on the file contents. Would it be possible for me to specifically store the entire file and the contents of it on Virtual Memory instead of physical memory?

If it is possible, then are there any side-effects/precautions that one should keep in mind?

The reason behind my question is that I often have to deal with such huge files or datasets (retrieved from databases) and perform operations on them, part of which need not occur sequentially or be synchronized. I want to improve the execution time and performance of the application by parallelizing the non sequential parts, if possible.

Comment: You could use memory mapped files for this, but the control of where you actually load objects into memory is outside of your control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you don't (and shouldn't need to) have any insight into how physical memory is managed. In Windows and hence in the CLR everything is virtual memory.

Unless you have a specific problem you should just pretend everything is physical memory.

You can depend on the operating system to intelligently determine what should be kept in physical memory and what can be swapped out. Swapping only occurs if there's memory pressure anyway, i.e. if you allocate more memory than is physically available.

Also, 100-200 MB isn't all that much nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

> physical or virtual memory

You can't actually read from virtual memory. When you attempt to this causes a page fault and the OS will do a [page swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) and bring that virtual memory back into physical memory. So you are only ever reading from physical memory. While swapping a page in, it will swap out a page from RAM that has not been used recently.

From the app's perspective it appears everything is in physical memory. You do not need to concern yourself with what pages are in or out of physical memory, the OS will handle that.